# ava.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer

Tags: android, socketexception

```
11-03 15:27:15.159: WARN/System.err(16482): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
11-03 15:27:15.169: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.read(Native Method)
11-03 15:27:15.169: WARN/System.err(16482):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.read(BlockGuard.java:273)
11-03 15:27:15.169: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:458)
11-03 15:27:15.169: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:85)
11-03 15:27:15.169: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
11-03 15:27:15.169: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
11-03 15:27:15.169: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
11-03 15:27:15.169: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
11-03 15:27:15.169: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
11-03 15:27:15.169: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
11-03 15:27:15.169: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
11-03 15:27:15.179: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
11-03 15:27:15.179: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
11-03 15:27:15.179: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:421)
11-03 15:27:15.189: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-03 15:27:15.189: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-03 15:27:15.189: WARN/System.err(16482):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-03 15:27:15.189: WARN/System.err(16482):     at com.chengjun.sns.domain.MyHttpClient.LogState(MyHttpClient.java:70)
11-03 15:27:15.199: WARN/System.err(16482):     at com.chengjun.sns.Login.validateLocalLogin(Login.java:167)
11-03 15:27:15.199: WARN/System.err(16482):     at com.chengjun.sns.Login.access$12(Login.java:160)
11-03 15:27:15.199: WARN/System.err(16482):     at com.chengjun.sns.Login$LoginFailureHandler.run(Login.java:325)
11-03 15:27:15.199: WARN/System.err(16482):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: have you added the required permissions in manifest file..